# Can we stop light in a lithium niobate crystal and then recover it later?

Tags: frequency, crystals, wavelength

Lithium niobate is a peculiar and important crystal, with piezoelectric, optical-electric, and photorefractive qualities giving it many applications due to these properties. It is transparent to wavelengths between 0.25 and 5.3 um. One application of these crystals are to construct frequency dividers and frequency doublers.

I was wondering, what if we use a frequency divider or frequency doubler to divide or double a wavelength in lithium niobate's transparent range into the opaque range of the lithium niobate crystal? Would the light be trapped in the opaque region of lithium niobate's transparency range, effectively stopping it?

Also, if this is possible, can we do the inverse; using frequency doubling if first frequency dividing, or using frequency dividing if first frequency doubling, in order to bring the trapped light back into the transparent range, effectively recovering the stopped light?

Comment: The way to achieve what you describe is a different nonlinear optical setting known as [slow light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_light).

Answer (score 3):

If a substance is [opaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opacity_(optics)) to light of a certain wavelength, this means that photons of light with that wavelength are absorbed and/or scattered in random directions by the substance. In either case, photons of light with wavelengths outside of the transparency window of a lithium niobate crystal will not simply be trapped inside the crystal. Instead, they will either be absorbed or scattered in random directions. In either case, the photons will not be recoverable in the way you suggest.